# 'ImportError: dlopen() Symbol not found' when trying to import Imfit library

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, homebrew

I was trying to install [Imfit](https://pyimfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) library using `pip3 install pyimfit` on an Intel Mac and this is the error i've got from Jupyter when trying to run `import pyimfit`

```py
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import pyimfit as im
      2 import scipy as sc
      3 import numpy as np

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyimfit/init.py:4, in <module>
      1 # This file defines what is visible to the outside world when the package
      2 # (pyimfit) is imported
      3 from .descriptions import *
----> 4 from .pyimfit_lib import convolve_image, make_imfit_function, ModelObjectWrapper  # type: ignore
      5 from .pyimfit_lib import FixImage
      6 from .pyimfit_lib import PsfOversampling

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyimfit/pyimfit_lib.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ZTTNSt3114basic_ifstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEE
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyimfit/pyimfit_lib.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyimfit/pyimfit_lib.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

I've tried reinstalling it through pip numerous times but to no avail. Also tried reinstalling Numpy/Scipy as those are the dependency for Imfit but also no luck. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you running an M1 Mac?  The `pyimfit` guys have made the mistake of bundling a binary library into their distribution.  If your compiler does not exactly match the one they used, the holes won't line up.  I can't tell if there is a user community to ask or not.